Where can I find information on the maximum number of bytes a processor supports for setting data breakpoints?
In Visual Studio, you can set breakpoints on data so that when the data is mutated, the breakpoint triggers. This appears to rely on hardware support, and my current processor only supports 4 bytes (Ryzen 7 4800H). Is anyone aware of the kind of support more modern processors have, and where I can find such info?

Your CPU hardware supports watchpoints that are 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes wide. Naturally aligned, so e.g. an 8-byte watchpoint is only possible on an address that's aligned by 8.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2009/ols2009-pages-149-158.pdf says x86-64 supports 8-byte watchpoints.  https://help.totalview.io/current/HTML/index.html#page/TotalView/Architectures.html also agrees that 1,2,4, and 8-byte naturally-aligned watchpoints are supported on x86-64 Linux, and explicitly says both Intel and AMD.  Both articles mention other ISAs, in case you're curious about those.
Totalview is a different debugger than VS.  Is it possible that an old 32-bit version of VS won't use 64-bit watchpoints, if your install of VS is several years old?  IIRC they kept the GUI itself 32-bit for many years.  Or perhaps the Windows kernel doesn't expose the full hardware capability, only allowing user-space to create up to 4-byte watchpoints?  (Totalview can only debug Linux / macOS targets, not Windows.)
On x86-64, hardware watchpoint support is from the debug registers, DR0-7.  The first 4 registers hold addresses.  The Linux article mentions some about what x86 debug registers do; this is a baseline part of the x86-64 ISA.  I haven't heard mention of CPUs providing extensions to that, like more DRs or an alternate API via MSRs, or wider watchpoints, or anything like that.  And neither totalview nor that 2009 Linux paper mention any CPU-specific limitations.
Hardware watchpoints - how do they work?  also links https://lwn.net/Articles/353050/
